# How to create a singleton QML type in Qt6 using cmake?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

I want to create a singleton QML type, preferably without any C++ code. Here is what I tried:

```
// ./themes/Theme.qml
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick

QtObject {
    readonly property string color: "indigo"
}
```

```
// ./Main.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import "./themes"

Window {
    color: Theme.color
    // ...
}
```

However it doesn't work: all properties on `Theme` in `Main.qml` are `undefined`. The suggestions I have seen are to add this line to `qmldir`:

```
singleton Theme 1.0 themes/Theme.qml
```

However `qmldir` is not supposed to be written manually in qt6, as it is generated automatically on build, and doing this doesn't work anyway. Another way is using `qmlRegisterSingletonType` from C++, but I don't really want to use C++ for this, and if I do this my singleton must be imported specifically as `import Theme 1.0` and not as other local `.qml` files (which can simply be used without any import statements if the file is in the same directory, or using `import "./path/to/dir"` otherwise).

Is there a way to do this only in QML?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? CMake should generate `qmldir` (and it seems to work), but I still cannot access any of the members of the singleton.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Only marking your `.qml` file with `pragma Singleton` is indeed not enough, it also must be marked as `singleton` in `qmldir`. But since `qmldir` is generated automatically, you need to specify that a particular file contains a singleton in cmake configuration. Add this to your `CMakeLists.txt` file and make sure it is written *before* the call to `qt_add_qml_module`:

```
set_source_files_properties(themes/Theme.qml PROPERTIES QT_QML_SINGLETON_TYPE TRUE)
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything.  Ubuntu 22.04 / Qt SDK 6.5.0.

Comment: I had to manually add the `qmldir` file to the build as a `RESOURCE` file to make the singleton work. I couldn't figure out why it was not working without this.

Comment: Not working with absolute or relative paths (on mac). qmldir is still generated without singleton command

Comment: +1 For noting the properties must be set before the files are added to the `qml_module`. Here's a reference to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-target-qml-sources.html#source-file-properties).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you put the `qmldir` inside the `Themes` folder, and the source would be updated to omit the `Theme` folder, i.e. `singleton Theme 1.0 Theme.qml`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import "themes"
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: Theme.color }
}

// themes/Theme.qml
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick

QtObject {
    readonly property string color: "indigo"
}

// themes/qmldir
singleton Theme 1.0 Theme.qml
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABEHicXY5BDoIwEEX3c4oJBwDdsvUAinqBAk2ttp06HRbEcHeLiAnO7s/P/+9bH4kFG2kG2z3AbmR5oCBMLq3/Qm7a61TASRmNL8B8reoehmkIfY1n3YkKxmUPO3LENV7nRPkROMEEUFW4tFSL9fQOIivjFV7snBUKfzsAGjm291z+ZbJWPQU3YmSKmmXEJJzDK7SwobeGii0vk3rLkFbKsg335Q5/U96N0l3e)